# How to create a simple "build" in Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maven

I am creating my first SPA in Angular and consuming a SpringBoot Rest API.

What I need is to create a simple "build" process, like Maven for Java projects, so I can handle differents environment constants. Is it possible to make it simple? I have seen very large config js and this is a simple project.

I have this in my app.js

```
angular.module('app', [ 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngMessages', 'ngStorage', 'ngAnimate', 'datatables', 
        'checklist-model', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert', 'ngSanitize', 
        'angucomplete-alt', 'localytics.directives', 'angular-peity'])
            .constant('config', {
                appName : 'MyApp',
                appVersion : '1.0.0',
                apiUrl : 'http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/',
                auth : {
                    url : 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token',
                    clientId : 'myAppOuath2',
                    header : 'Basic c29mdGFs123456F1dGgyOlh6NnFnamhwwxx=',
                    grantType : 'password'
                }
            })
...
```

And I want to automatize the urls with wildcards like this:

```
...
apiUrl : '{apiUrl}',
auth : {
    url : '{authUrl}',
    clientId : '{clientId}',
    header : '{authHeader}',
    grantType : 'password'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out grunt-preprocess: https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiarized with maven. I've always used Gulp or Grunt to build my SPA apps.

You can generate some `config.js` (with Grunt I use ngconstant plugin):

```
ngconstant: {
  options: {
    name: 'config',
    space: '  ',
    dest: 'app/config.js'
  },
  local: {
    constants: {
      ENV: 'local'
    }
  },

  dev: {
    constants: {
      ENV: 'dev'
    }
  }
}
```

To build:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
    grunt.task.run([
      'ngconstant:' + target
    ])
})
```

`$ grunt build:local`

When the `config.js` is generated, the next step is include it in your app.js

`angular.module('myApp', ['config'])`

Comment: Maven is for Java projects. Nothing to do with JS. Shall you show me an example of that "config.js"?